# Xero Api , How create "Multiple Item" in a single bank transaction

Tags: php, xero-api

If a user creates one overpayment with the UI inside an invoice, automatically Xero creates, in Bank Transaction, a transaction called **"Payment:multiple items"**. Inside the transaction, Xero UI shows "Transaction: View Transaction" with two areas, one for the **Invoice Payments** and the other for the **Overpayments and Prepayments.**

Is possible , with the XERO API, create a bank transaction with Multiple Items?. How it is done?

I tried with the API create an Overpayment through Bank Transaction and a Payment , both with the same Contact, but the UI Bank Transaction menu shows two different Bank Transaction.

Answer (score 0):

Support answered me:

> Unfortunately it is not possible to achieve the same thing via API.
>
> In the web interface, you can essentially create overpayment in two
>   ways, via the bank account screen and also by creating payment that
>   are larger than the amount owed in an invoice.
>
> With API, the overpayment is created via BankTransactions endpoint, so
>   essentially the same as the first method in the web UI. However, it is
>   not possible to post payment amount that are larger than the amount
>   owed via API.